# jquery rotate only works on 1 image in IE7

Tags: javascript, jquery, rotation, internet-explorer-7

I have 2 images I want to rotate

I am using jQuery rotate, which works fine in any modern browsers, and according to its documentation works for IE 6 +

LINK TO PLUGIN : [Plugin](https://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/)

My problem is that in IE < 9, I can only get 1 image to rotate on a page, if I try any more they dont work properly (the first animates as expected, then when its time for the second they both break)

Any ideas or is this a known issue?

JS:

```
$circle_50.rotate({
    angle: 0,
    animateTo:180,
    duration:400,
    center:["100%","50%"],
    easing:linear
});

setTimeout(function(){
    $circle_50_100.rotate({
        angle: 0,
        animateTo:deg - 180,
        duration:400,
        center:["0%","50%"],
        easing:linear
    });
},400);
```

HTML:

```
<div id="percent-complete-circle-wrap">
    <img id="percent-50" src="/images/cand-percent-low.jpg" />
    <img id="percent-50-100" src="/images/cand-percent-low.jpg" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#percent-50,
#percent-50-100{
    display:block;
    position: absolute;
    top:0px;
    height:100px;
    width:50px;
}

#percent-50{
    left:0px;
    z-index:3;
}

#percent-50-100{
    right:0px;
    z-index:1;
}

#percent-complete-circle-wrap{
    position:relative;
    margin:0 auto 20px auto;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: Please link to the plugin you are using. Have you checked if it's compatible with older IE?

Comment: what is the value of deg?

Comment: @ n0mercy - its a value from 0-360, depending on what 'percent complete' a users profile is, e.g if profile is 75% complete, it is 270

Comment: who supports ie 7-8 anyways?